# How do I link to a new page and load a div with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a primary landing page with a filter navigation on the left, and a listing of different article types on the right. When a user clicks on an article, they go to a new landing page, but I have a copy of that filter navigation on the left, so that they can click on a new filter to go back to the primary page with a revised listing or articles.

My html looks like:

```
<li><a href="#internet-nav" id="internet-nav-articles">Internet Articles</a></li>
```

my content should load in:

```
<div id="#insights-div-articles"> </div>
```

and my javascript looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".-categories a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
$("#internet-nav-articles").on("click", function(){
    $(window.location = '/insights-and-news/internet-articles/').load("insights-category-divs/internet-articles-tab #insights-div-articles");
});

});
```

Thank you in advance for any help, I'm sure my javascript is way off, just trying to learn

Comment: Where did you learn that `$(window.location = ...` syntax? What do you expect when you mix jquery with html dom elements in that case?

Comment: why don't you just use a normal link (since you're triying to do a window.location anyway)?

Comment: I'm trying to link to a new page but load something different than the default of what is loaded in the div. For example, by default, I am loading content from `/insights-category-divs/all-categories-tab` in `<div id="#insights-div-articles"> </div>`, but if the user clicks on a different filter from the article landing page, I want it to load content from `insights-category-divs/internet-articles-tab`

Comment: ok. The (one) way to do that is to add a parameter to the link, such as `mylink.php?category=internet` and deal with that via php.

Comment: You _can not_ load a page and after that change it's content from the origin page (unless it's an iframe or smth).

Comment: If you want to build a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) you might want to have a look at one of the many frameworks for that, like angularjs, Emberjs

Comment: Ok, I'll try that with php, thank you very much, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the parameters suggestion from the comments above. There is probably a cleaner way to do this, but my final code looks like:

For example, a user clicks on http://www.example.com/#filter=internet

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var url = window.location.href;
var insightfilter = url.split('#')[1].split('=');
insightfilter.shift();

if (insightfilter == 'internet') {
    $.get("/insights-category-divs/internet-articles-tab", function(data) {
    $("#insights-div-articles").html(data);

    $('.-categories a').removeClass('-active');
    $('#internet-insights-link-articles').addClass('-active');
    history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
    });
}

});
```

The removeClass and addClass are to set the correct filter as highlighted when going back to the primary page. The history.pushState removes the #whatever from the url if a user switches to another filter on the primary landing page.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `history` API. It looks like you want to load new content as well as change the URL in the bar. You can do that with something like:

`history.pushState(data, "page 2", "bar.html");`

See these resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API
- https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/